# Asp.net Debugging Not Working

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

[Asp.net Debugging not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJnib.jpg)

Hi,
I am trying to run and debug my asp.net application. But i am getting the below error :
**Unable to start debugging on the web server.Could not start ASP.NET debugging. More information may be available by starting the project without debugging.**

You can refer the screen shot as well from the above link.

Comment: what ASP.NET server are you targeting for debug?

Comment: I am debugging using local  machine.

Comment: It's likely to be a problem of permission. Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: Yes i am running my Visual Studio as an administrator. Not yet resolved :(

Comment: are you able to Attach the Debugger to the IIS process?

Comment: Thanks Peval27 for your support. I got this resolved by removing the application from IIS and again adding them. Don't know the exact cause why this happened.

Comment: In this case, I'd write your solution as an answer for future memory and other people who may experience the same issue. Also upvote any useful comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps might help.

1. Restart the app and then try restarting IIS
2. If the web server is local, try attaching to the server process
3. If the web server is local, try attaching to the server process
4. If the web server is remote, make sure the remote debugger is running

for more info goto original [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Nabeel, for your response. I got this resolve by adding the application again into IIS and removing the older ones. :)

Comment: @Rahul Parab, if Nabeel Khan's reply is helpful for you, you can mark it as the answer:)